# C# variable, .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in C#, Help me please in:

I have a dropdown list and some labels and

**each ListItem VALUE from DDL is equal with each label ID**

for example

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
                     <asp:ListItem Text="Route A - Toronto to Barrie" Value="RouteA">
                </asp:DropDownList>

               <asp:Label ID="RouteA" runat="server" Text="42"></asp:Label>
```

QUESTION:

```
 private Label ccc;

public void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ccc.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

**I my code is not what i Want.**

I want to get selectet item value (**DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()**) from DDL and put in some Variable (**this.ccc**) and after that I want to call label with the same ID .

**Logical I want Something like this :**

this.ccc = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(); (in My case this.ccc = "RouteA")

this.ccc.Text ="test" (in My case)  (this.ccc.Text = "42");

Thank You very much, if You've understood, Please Help me !!

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't understand this...

Comment: I want to get select.value from LISTitem, put it in same variable, 

and after that call a LABEL who has the same ID

for example logical in Javascript 

var test =selectet.item.val;

Label.TEXT=test.Text;

Comment: I think you should name your drop down list something a bit more descriptive than DropDownList1. If it containes routes, why not call it something like routeDropDownList?

Comment: Joren, that is true but a little beside the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but:

```
// this returns the ID of the label
string labelId = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

// now find the label with that ID
Label label = FindControl(labelId) as Label;

this.ccc.Text = label.Text;
```

Comment: Label label = FindControl(labelId) as Label;

after compile, Label labelID (null)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with your comment.

Answer (score 2):

How about this :

```
Label myLabel = (Label)Page.FindControl(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
myLabel.Text = "test";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to try somewhat like this.

Control c = Page.FindControl(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
//You can choose to use other container than the Page instance itself

Label l = c as Label;

l.Text = "test";

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Page.FindControl`.

```
Label label = (Label)Page.FindControl(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
this.ccc.Text = label.Text;
```

I don't believe you need to call `ToString()` on the `SelectedValue` property because it is a string by definition.

There's a chance that your controls are deep within the page hierarchy, so you can use Jeff Atwood's recursive FindControl method (stolen from his one of his [blog articles](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/)):

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
  if (root.ID == id)
  { 
    return root; 
  } 

  foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
  { 
    Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
    if (t != null) 
    { 
      return t; 
    } 
  } 

  return null; 
}
```

Your code will change to:

```
Label label = (Label)FindControlRecursive(Page, DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
this.ccc.Text = label.Text;
```